# Borel measurable function, Borel set, probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Show that for two independent random variables $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m, Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$, Borel measurable function $g: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and a Borel set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have:

$$P(g(X, Y) \in B) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} P( \ g(x, Y) \in B \ ) \ \text{d}P_X(x).$$

I've shown that

$$\mathbb{E}(g(X, Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \mathbb{E}( \ g(x, Y) \ ) \ \text{d}P_X(x).$$

So now it's just a matter of restricting it to $B \subset \mathbb{R}$.

But I am not sure how to write it down formally. It seems so straightforward.

Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Let $1_B$ denote the characteristic function of the set $B$. In other words, $1_B(x)=1$ if $x \in B$ and $1_B(x)=0$ if $x \notin B$.

Define $h:=1_B \circ g:\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. From what you've shown before, we already know that $$E(h(X, Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \mathbb{E}( \ h(x, Y) \ ) \ \text{d}P_X(x).$$

But notice that $E(h(X,Y))=E(1_B(g(X,Y)))=P(g(X,Y) \in B)$. This is because $1_B(g(X,Y))=1 $ if and only if $ g(X,Y) \in B$.

Similarly, notice that $E(h(x,Y))=P(g(x,Y)\in B)$.